# Is it possible in bash to complete the middle of a word?

Tags: bash, tab-completion

I have a simple bash completion script for my custom git branch searcher.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
_branch_completions()
{
  local word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";
  if [ ! -z "$word" ]
  then
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "`git branch | grep $word`" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
  fi
}

complete -F _branch_completions branch
```

The "branch" script searches within branches so I can search for

```
branch 5.9
```

and I'll get

```
1 release/5.9.0
2 hotfix/5.9.1
3 hotfix/5.9.2
Please select a branch
```

My bash completion script will complete branch rele <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>
and give me release/5.9.0 but I'd like to be able to do branch 5.9 <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and get all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
compgen [option] [word]
...
    If word is specified, only those completions matching word will be displayed.
```

You're already filtering the list with grep, so to get the behaviour you want you can simply omit the second argument to compgen, making your line:

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "`git branch | grep $word`"))
```

Comment: That worked, but after using it, it's not so great :\  if "develop" is near the end of the branch name there's no way that I can find to select it, without backspacing and retyping

Answer (score 0):

Necropost, but worth mentioning for further readers:
even without compgen readline lib by itself may add some mess when it comes to ambiguous matches and common prefixes:

```
function _bash_completion_smth() {
        COMPREPLY=(1aaa2 2aaa3 3bbb4)
}
$ complete -F _bash_completion_smth smth
$ smth[TAB][TAB]
1aaa2 2aaa3 3bbb4
$ smth aaa[TAB][TAB]
1aaa2 2aaa3 3bbb4
$ # word 3bbb4 is undesired
```

This aspects are controlled by readline lib's variables

> show-all-if-ambiguous (Off)
> This alters the default behavior of the completion >functions.  If set to On, words which have more than one possible >completion cause the matches to be listed immediately instead of ringing >the bell.

> show-all-if-unmodified (Off)
> This alters the default behavior of the completion functions in a fashion similar to show-all-if-ambiguous.  If set to On, words which have more than one possible completion without any possible partial completion (the possible completions don't share a common prefix)  cause  the  matches  to  be listed immediately instead of ringing the bell.

Readline lib's variables can be tweaked directly in completion func with
`bind "set variable value"`

Details for both vars explained here [show-all-if-ambiguous vs show-all-if-unmodified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192384/show-all-if-ambiguous-vs-show-all-if-unmodified)